# までvsにかけてのちがい全くわかりません

Tags: grammar

**まで**vs**にかけて**のちがいは何でしょうか？
教えてくれてありがたいです。
返事待っています。

Answer (score 1):

AからBまで：　A → → → B

AからBにかけて：　A x x x B

東京から大阪まで行った：(1) 東京を出て大阪に着いた（この場合の「まで」と「に」のちがいは「まで」は「そんなにも遠く」という感じがすることです）(2) 「東京から大阪にかけて行った」と同じ

東京から大阪にかけて行った：東京に行き、名古屋に行き、京都に行き、大阪に行った（一度の機会に行ったかもしれないし、別々かもしれない）

（ちなみに、「教えてくれてありがたい」の使い方がまちがっています。まだ誰も教えてないので「教えてくれて」とは言えません）

Comment: **にかけて**というのは、直接ではなくて、目的地へ行っているときに、その他の地方へも行ったということですか。

Comment: @QING いいえ、目的地ではなく範囲の終端を表しています。

Comment: コメントを訂正します。「直接行ったかどうかは、関係がないので、わからない」です。

Answer (score 1):

英語で言うと、「かけて」はover,「まで」は、"until"って感じです。「かけて」のほうがその期間その動作が続いているイメージを強く持たせられると思います。

一つ違う点は、「かけて」には"by"の使い方がないという事です。例えば、「明日五時までにここに来てください(Could you come here by 5:00 p.m. tomorrow)」とは言えますが、「明日の五時にかけてここに来てください。」は不自然です。